# Media Queries not working in my HTML code, Not sure what I am doing wrong here

Tags: css, wordpress, html, media-queries

This is my Code for a FAST click on a website.

Website URL: [www.vegastoothdr.com/wp_site/](http://www.vegastoothdr.com/wp_site/)

```
<body>
<div id="wpadminbar" style="background-color: black; padding-top: 0px;border-color: white;">
      <span class="row" style="vertical-align: top">

        <!-- PHONE ICON -->   
        <a href="tel:(702) 473-5100">
        <img class="icons" src="http://www.vegastoothdr.com/wp_site/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/phone.png" width="60" height="36" style="padding-left: 20px">
        </a>

        <!-- CALENDAR ICON -->  
        <a href="appointment">
        <img class="icons" src="http://www.vegastoothdr.com/wp_site/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/calendar.png" width="60" height="36" style="padding-left: 20px">
        </a>

        <!-- EMAIL ICON -->   
        <a href="contact">
        <img class="icons" src="http://www.vegastoothdr.com/wp_site/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/envelope.png" width="67" height="36" style="padding-left: 20px">
        </a>

        <!-- PIN ICON -->     
        <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/1070+W+Horizon+Ridge+Pkwy+%23121,+Henderson,+NV+89012,+USA/@36.022368,-115.0346407,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x80c8d16f85764fa7:0x702e5efb00bd1ffb">
        <img class="icons" src="http://www.vegastoothdr.com/wp_site/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/pin.png" width="49" height="36" style="padding-left: 20px">
        </a>

      </span>
    </div>
<header>
<!-- Nav CODE -->
</header>
```

Okay, Now i have the CODE and I placed a CSS code on the last line on the `<head>`section

```
@media screen and (max-width: 782px) 
    {

      div#wpadminbar 
        {

          height: 55px;
          min-width: 300px;
        }
    }
```

Okay... It works on the mobile device now.

But, The links are not working. So i cant click the icons. none of the links are working.

---

TEST TWO:

I placed it under the Header Section and the links works.. But the media query is not working. Soo weird.

I have placed the code below where the links are working but the media query is not working.

```
<body>

<header>
  <div id="wpadminbar" style="background-color: black; padding-top: 0px;border-color: white;">
  <span class="row" style="vertical-align: top">

    <!-- PHONE ICON -->   
    <a href="tel:(702) 473-5100">
    <img class="icons" src="http://www.vegastoothdr.com/wp_site/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/phone.png" width="60" height="36" style="padding-left: 20px">
    </a>

    <!-- CALENDAR ICON -->  
    <a href="appointment">
    <img class="icons" src="http://www.vegastoothdr.com/wp_site/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/calendar.png" width="60" height="36" style="padding-left: 20px">
    </a>

    <!-- EMAIL ICON -->   
    <a href="contact">
    <img class="icons" src="http://www.vegastoothdr.com/wp_site/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/envelope.png" width="67" height="36" style="padding-left: 20px">
    </a>

    <!-- PIN ICON -->     
    <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/1070+W+Horizon+Ridge+Pkwy+%23121,+Henderson,+NV+89012,+USA/@36.022368,-115.0346407,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x80c8d16f85764fa7:0x702e5efb00bd1ffb">
    <img class="icons" src="http://www.vegastoothdr.com/wp_site/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/pin.png" width="49" height="36" style="padding-left: 20px">
    </a>

  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: your header is fixed position

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, There was JS script that was adding a Div for Video. It seems the DIV was on top on my code.

I deleted it and it fixed it :)

Link to the site: http://www.vegastoothdr.com/